# Is there anyway to style html elements through html classes with variables?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm just curious to know if it is possible to have specific stylings based on the name of of a class.

For example, Bootstrap 4 has a helper class for margins and padding like:

`<div class="m-t-1 p-a-0"></div>`

This gives the div 1em of margin to the top, and removes padding from all sides.

I am sure they have pre-styled this class in their CSS to achieve this.
But I am curious if there is a way to use the class as a variable.

for example:

`<div class="fs-x"></div>`

where `x` can be any number, this class would then give the styling the `font-size: x` to the div.

Is this possible to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CSS pre-processor such as SASS or LESS to achieve this however it generates static classes within a specified range below is an example from the [SASS documentation](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while):

```
$class-slug: for !default

@for $i from 1 through 4
  .#{$class-slug}-#{$i}
    width: 60px + $i
```

**Which emits this CSS:**

```
.for-1 {
  width: 61px;
}

.for-2 {
  width: 62px;
}

.for-3 {
  width: 63px;
}

.for-4 {
  width: 64px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All CSS classes must be explicitly defined. So every variation if X would need to exist in a .css file

Answer (score 0):

you can use constant in css for example

```
$x = 10px;

img{
   margin-bottom : $x;
}
```

but however you can declare variables with this way

```
:root {
  --color-principal: #06c;
}

#foo h1 {
  color: var(--color-principal);
}
```